# Can someone define efficiency?

Tags: efficiency

There are lots of questions about efficiency in CrossValidated, but I am no a sophisticated statistician. All I want is a simple layman's definition of efficiency.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the money quote from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_%28statistics%29):

> Essentially, a more efficient estimator, experiment or test needs fewer samples than a less efficient one to achieve a given performance.

You can also look at [the Wikipedia entry on "efficient estimators"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficient_estimator).